# Kendo grid sorting in desc order

Tags: grails, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid in my Grails app and my requirement is to sort "date" column in descending order as soon as the row get inserted, so that most recent date comes at the top row in the grid.

How do I sort by the date column?

Answer (score 17):

Default sort criteria is a property on your dataSource:

```
sort: { field: "date", dir: "desc"}
```